# What is the expected value of the mean of a random subset?

Tags: probability, statistics

Lets say you have a set $A$ made up of $n$ integers. We then randomly choose $m$ distinct elements from $A$ and put them in a set $B$.

How would you prove that the expected value of the mean of $B$ is equal to the mean of $A$?

Namely $E\left[\dfrac{1}{m}\sum_ja_j\right] = \dfrac{1}{n}\sum_ia_i$ where $j$ represents each of the random integers in $B$ and $i$ represents the items in $A$.

Comment: Context required. $A$ is a subset of $\mathbb{N}$, $\mathbb{Z}$, $\mathbb{R}$ ? What is the $\sigma$-algebra $\Sigma \subseteq \mathcal{P}(A)$ and the measure $\mu$ on $\Sigma$ which you pick the subset of $A_0 \subseteq A$ from, so that the mean of this set $$\int_{A_0} x \, \mathrm{d} \mu(x)$$ makes sense? What do you mean by uniformly choosing an element from $\Sigma$ ?

Comment: @Adayah Way to go overcomplitacing the issue. I think the wording of the question is clear enough to assume the user is not a measure theiry expert.

Comment: @5xum Maybe, but I wanted to be more specific than "please provide more context". Also, I'm far from being a measure theory expert as well...

Comment: @Adayah I added more context.

Comment: The context is not enough. For providing context to this question, you have to mention precisely how $m$ elements are randomly chosen. For example, if I let $A$ be just the set of integers, then $A$ has infinitely many elements, and so giving all subsets of $A$ the same probability of occuring would not work. Then, some subsets will be preferred to others, and the context you have to provide, is which subsets are preferred. Now, if $A$ is *finite*, then you can assume that all subsets are chosen with the same probability, and the question is fine.

Comment: Ok, but still a bit more is needed. Does $A$ have exactly $n$ elements?

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг oversight, sorry, yes it has n elements.

Comment: @Adayah sorry, added that detail.

Comment: @DMan That was literally the most important detail of the whole story. Now, we can get to work on this question.

Answer (score 1):

Lets write $b_i$ for the $i$th selected  element (also assume the subset is chosen uniformly at random); each of the elements $a_1,...,a_n$ are equally likely to be selected to be $b_i$ and therefore, $\mathbb Eb_i = \frac{1}{n}∑_{i=1}^n a_i$. By linearity of expectation,

$$ \mathbb E \frac{1}{m} \sum_{i=1}^m b_i = \frac{1}{m} \sum_{i=1}^m \mathbb E b_i = \frac{1}{m} \sum_{i=1}^m \left( \frac{1}{n}∑_{j=1}^n a_j\right) = \frac{1}{n}∑_{i=1}^n a_i $$

Comment: Can you expand a little more how you inferred that Ebi is that?

Comment: Impose the ordering uniformly at random if that is concerning you; this will not affect the final answer. Choosing the set uniformly at random means that $b_1$ and $b_2$ are both just as likely to be $a_1$, etc.

Comment: Indeed, but since my definition of E[x] is super rusty, I am a bit confused. Isn't the expected value $E[b_i] = b_i P(b_i \in B)$, for all $i$ ? in this case, I understand that the probability is equal across all $b_i$, but what happens to $b_i$ itself?

Comment: @DMan $\mathbb E[b_i] := \sum_{k=1}^n a_k P(b_i = a_k)$. The equally likely bit forces all the probabilities to be the same $1/n$.

Answer (score 0):

1. Let $A = \{ a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_n \}$ and define

   $$F(x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n) = \frac{1}{\binom{n}{m}} \sum \left \{ \mathbb{M}( X_0 ) : X_0 \subseteq \{ x_1, \ldots, x_n \}, \ |X_0| = m \right\}$$

   where $\displaystyle \mathbb{M}(X_0) = \frac{1}{m} \sum_{x \in X_0} x$ is the mean of $X_0$. Then $F(a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_n)$ is the expectation of the mean of a random subset $A_0 \subseteq A$ consisting of $m$ elements.
2. Expanding the above definition may be laborious, but it's evident that there exist $\alpha_1, \alpha_2, \ldots, \alpha_n \in \mathbb{R}$ such that

   $$(\forall x_1, \ldots, x_n \in \mathbb{Z}) \, F(x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n) = \sum_{k=1}^n \alpha_k \cdot x_k,$$

   because each $\mathbb{M}(X_0)$ is some linear combination of $x_i$'s within $X_0$, these are added up and divided by a constant $\binom{n}{m}$.

   It's sufficient to show that $\alpha_i = \alpha_j$ for all $i, j \in \{ 1, \ldots, n \}$, for that leads to $\alpha_i = \frac{1}{n}$ and it follows that $F(a_1, \ldots, a_n) = \mathbb{M}(A)$.
3. Let $\sigma : \{ 1, \ldots, n \} \to \{ 1, \ldots, n \}$ be a permutation. Then $\{ x_{\sigma(1)}, \ldots, x_{\sigma(n)} \} = \{ x_1, \ldots, x_n \}$, hence

   $$\begin{align*}
   F(x_{\sigma(1)}, \ldots, x_{\sigma(n)}) & = \frac{1}{\binom{n}{m}} \sum \left \{ \mathbb{M}( X_0 ) : X_0 \subseteq \{ x_{\sigma(1)}, \ldots, x_{\sigma(n)} \}, \ |X_0| = m \right\} \\[1ex] & = \frac{1}{\binom{n}{m}} \sum \left \{ \mathbb{M}( X_0 ) : X_0 \subseteq \{ x_1, \ldots, x_n \}, \ |X_0| = m \right\} = F(x_1, \ldots, x_n).
   \end{align*}$$
4. Let $i, j \in \{ 1, \ldots, n \}$ and let $\sigma$ be the transposition $(i \ j)$. Also let

   $$z_k = \begin{cases} 1 & \text{for } k = j \\ 0 & \text{for } k \neq j \end{cases}$$

   so

   $$z_{\sigma(k)} = \begin{cases} 1 & \text{if } k = i \\ 0 & \text{if } k \neq i \end{cases}$$

   By 2. and 3.

   $$\alpha_j = F(z_1, \ldots, z_n) = F(z_{\sigma(1), \ldots, \sigma(n)}) = \alpha_i$$

   which concludes the proof.